# No route to host error in socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a simple client program which connects to a the ip address "172.31.1.34" and sends a message. Everything works fine but I am not able to recieve any message from the server. The error says "no route to host".
My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    int s1,s2,len;
    int n;
    char buffer[500];

    strcpy(buffer,"GET http://172.31.1.34/ HTTP/1.0\n\n");
    bzero((char *)&client,sizeof(client));
    client.sin_port = htons(80);
    client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.31.1.34");
    client.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s2 = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);

    if(connect(s2,(struct sockaddr *)&client,sizeof(client)) == -1) {
        perror("can't connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n = send(s2,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    if(n < 0) {
        perror("message not sent");
        exit(1);
    }
    while(1) {
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        n = recv(s2,buffer,500,0);
        if(n < 0) {
            perror("coudnot read");
            exit(1);
        }
        buffer[n] = '\0';
        printf("%s",buffer);
    }

    close(s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `SOCK_DGRAM`? That is for UDP packets. HTML uses TCP. You should use `SOCK_STREAM`

Comment: Thanks for pionting out the mistake. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have only briefly looked at your code, but at first glance it seems OK. However I would start with the obvious - maybe there is no route to the host....

Assuming you are on Linux or other Unix platform (including OSX), I would do the  following:

- `ping 172.31.1.34`. Note this does not guarantee the host is not available as ping may be blocked.
- `telnet 172.31.1.34`. This should connect and you can enter your HTTP query directly
- `tcptraceroute 172.31.1.34 80`

If all of these fail, the problem is the network, not your code.

On OSX, you can install tcptraceroute from "homebrew". On Linux use your normal package manager (or ask your system managers).

Comment: Ping,telnet and tcptraceroute all are working properly. When I send the a message using telnet, I get a reply.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below instead:

```
client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.31.1.34");
inet_pton(AF_INET, "172.31.1.34", &client.sin_addr);
```

Comment: Please format your code using code blocks, not highlight.